# getting error module "react" not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify, flux

I'm attempting to set up a flux react environment, I watched the tutorial here: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-development-environment-setup, I have copied and pasted the exact code that works in the tutorial vid ( it is all available below the video ) but every time I run it I get the following error:

```
Error: module "react" not found from "/flux/src/js/fake_179946b1.js"
at notFound (/flux/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/index.js:803:15)
at /flux/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/index.js:754:23
at /flux/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:185:24
at /flux/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:44:14
at process (/flux/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:113:43)
at /flux/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:122:21
at load (/flux/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:54:43)
at /flux/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:60:22
at /flux/node_modules/gulp-browserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:16:47
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
```

I dont understand, everything is copied and pasted, except for the package.json file which is the same except it has the most recent releases. here is a copy of it:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "gulp-browserify":"^0.5.0",
    "gulp-concat":"^2.4.1",
    "react":"^0.11.2",
    "reactify":"^0.14.0",
    "es6-promises":"^1.0.10",
  }
}
```

what is going wrong? were there breaking changes in the new releases that anyone might be aware of making this code no longer valid? other then that I don't know what it could be as it clearly works in the video tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you change the React.renderComponent(...) method, to React.render(...) in the src/js/main.js file, it works fine.